# Equivalent of http://localhost/Odata/User(1)/Contacts in .NET webapi Odata Client

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am working on an WebApi based OData service with navigated properties. I can get results using filter and contacts however what i am interested is in whether is there a way of expressing in .net which would resolve in Contacts query to the server. The goal is to achieve the result by using the proxy classes generated on client side.

```
http://mydevserver/Odata/User(1)/Contacts
```

Trying This

```
 Dim query = From c In cont.User.Expand("Contacts") Where c.Id = userId
```

Results In

```
http://localhost/Odata/User(1)?$expand=Contacts
```

Gives me This 
I have tried using LINQ and inline query but i cannot produce exact same query. If i run that same in fiddler. I can see the results of the related contacts for the user. May be i am missing something. Can please somebody point me in right direction.
Thanks

Comment: show us what you have code

Comment: If the result is identical why does it matter what the url looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using OData Client, You can try following codes.

```
    Dim queryUser = (From p In cont.UserWhere c.Id = userId).First()
    Dim contact As QueryOperationResponse(Of Contact) = cont.LoadProperty(queryUser, "Contacts")
```

This code will send two request:

~/Odata/User(1)

~/Odata/User(1)/Contacts